# solving Differential Equation (hint)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(yy')^3 = 27x(y^2-2x^2)$$
I tried a lot, but one what i see is $yy'=(y^2)'$ and then we get $z'^3 = 216x(z-2x^2)$
I have no idea, please, hint a substitution.

Comment: you forgot the prime in the final equation. Also $yy' = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(y^2\right)'$

Comment: yes, thank you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y = \sqrt{2}x v$
$$
2xv(xv)' = \left(27\cdot 2 x^3\left(v^2-1\right)\right)^{1/3} = 3(2)^{1/3}x\left(v^2-1\right)^{1/3}
$$
or 
$$
2xv^2 + 2x^2vv' = 3(2)^{1/3}x\left(v^2-1\right)^{1/3}
$$
Can you see how to finish it? Let $u =v^2$
$$
x^2u' = 2x\left(3(2)^{-2/3}\left(u-1\right)^{1/3} -u\right)
$$

Comment: No.In my opinion, it became worse)

Comment: It becomes separable now I do admit the integral is tricky,

Comment: yes, thank, got it

Comment: is it a good answer? 
$$ \frac{(\frac{y^2}{2x^2}-1)^{4/3}}{2^{7/3}} - ln{\frac{|y|}{\sqrt(2)}}= C$$